# Replicate background on last line of GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I have a GridView with four columns, on each item I added my library background (a shelf styled one), but the problem is, on the last line if there's less than four itens, the background goes only until the last item, I need it to fill the row, how can I do that?

That's my actual code:

```
public class LibraryGridView extends GridView {
    private LibraryActivity activity;

    public LibraryGridView(LibraryActivity activity) {
        super(activity);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(223, 223, 223));

        this.activity = activity;

        setNumColumns(activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? 6 : 4);
    }

    public void setData(List<LibraryItem> books) {
        setAdapter(new BookAdapter(getContext(), books));
    }

    private class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LibraryItem> {
        private List<LibraryItem> books;

        public BookAdapter(Context context, List<LibraryItem> books) {
            super(context, 0, books);
            this.books = books;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            BookGridView view = null;

            if (convertView == null)
                view = new BookGridView(activity);
            else
                view = (BookGridView) convertView;

            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_grid);
            view.loadStateFrom(getItem(position));

            return view;
        }

        public LibraryItem getItem(int id) {
            return books.get(id);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return books.size();
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For try purpose can you add empty item at the last of private List<LibraryItem> books and then pass it to array adapter? so yout list contain n+1 item. try it and let me know what happen?

Comment: Well, I solved this way, I added empty itens, and also return null on getItem, and the only thing drawed is the background. Ty

Comment: So I think you should always add item on list in multiple of 4, because you have a 4 columns, and its works. If you don't mind I write the about comment as a answer so you will accept it and it helpful for you and other user also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to `add empty item at the last of private List<LibraryItem> books in multiple of 4` and then pass it to array adapter, so yout list contain (n%4 = 0) item.

Here usage of 4 because your gridview has a 4 columns.

Thanks.